# Determine if a Python file is running in Blender?

Tags: python

My add-on needs to run both inside and outside of Blender (I have unit tests that I run with a headless version of Blender to make sure everything continues to work).

How do I determine in my `__init__.py` file if my package is being loaded and ran in Blender versus being loaded in just normal Python?

What I've tried:

- `globals()` does not seem to contain anything useful to check at least in a loaded Python file. It has quite a few things in the Python console as well as when running a file from the TextEditor in Blender.
- [`sys.modules[__name__].__addon_enabled__`](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/eb6fe5fa94b86a0a20742e06bf1e68b4cbaf6693/release/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py#L368) does not seem to work
- `try: import bpy` work for my case as I have a module in my environment called `bpy` (headless Blender)

Comment: My workaround for now is that for my unit tests there's an environment variable set to tell it that's it shouldn't try to do normal Blender registration.

Comment: What about `sys.argv` ?

Comment: Damn, that's a clever idea... I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 2):

**edit: This answer will not work since Blender 2.91 because the meaning of `sys.executable` changed, see https://developer.blender.org/rB04c5471ceefb41c9e49bf7c86f07e9e7b8426bb3.**

---

I found an example of this on the "Blender as a python module" wiki: https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy/wiki/Caveat---Importing-Addons#development-of-new-gui-addons

Their suggestion is to test `os.path.basename(sys.executable)` for a prefix of "blender" vs "python", eg.

```
in_blender = os.path.basename(sys.executable or '').lower().startswith('blender')
```

(Testing `sys.executable` is a little better than `sys.argv[0]`. A script with a shebang line called like `./blender-script.py` will have a `sys.argv[0]` of "./blender_script.py" (giving a false positive), while its `sys.executable` will still be the path to the python interpreter.)

Another idea is to test that `sys.executable` is the same as [`bpy.app.binary_path`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.binary_path)

```
try:
    import bpy
    in_blender = (sys.executable == bpy.app.binary_path)
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    in_blender = False
```

Comment: Wouldn't `os.path.samefile(sys.executable, bpy.app.binary_path)` been more robust again file system?